# How to prevent directory access after baserewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my .htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/f/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /f/$1 [L]
```

This basically makes it so when someone accesses a file from / its actually reading files from /f/ without the user knowing it.

The problem is that I have multiple domains that are all using "domain forwarding" to point to my actual domain. For example:

```
mydomain.com -> mydomain.io
```

When accessing mydomain.com for some reason the url ends up on `mydomain.io/f/` instead of `mydomain.io`

So what I am looking to do is prevent accessing `mydomain.io/f/` entirely and only allowing files to be accessed directly from `mydomain.io`

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: @anubhava In the network tab I have caching disabled, I have "all" selected for the filter. When accessing `mydomain.io` everything shows as 200 status. Equally when accessing `mydomain.io/f/` everything shows as status 200. When accessing `mydomain.com` I get a `301 redirect for mydomain.com initiator other` and `301 redirect on mydomain.io initiator mydomain.com`

Comment: @anubhava When accessing `mydomain.com` it redirects to `mydomain.io/f/` but not when accessing `mydomain.io`.

Comment: ok because you wrote `mydomain.io/f/` in question. Anyway so when you access `mydomain.com` with caching disabled it redirects with `301` to `mydomain.com/f/` ?

Comment: I am not sure if I am being clear here. Website is at mydomain.io. I have domain forwarding on mydomain.com to mydomain.io. When accessing mydomain.com it should be ending up on mydomain.io and instead is ending up on mydomain.io/f/. I have tested this with caching off, in an incognito window, even with tor browser. The .com domain is definitely directing to the mydomain.io/f/ folder

Comment: It appears domain forwarding is happening after your .htaccess rules have run.

Comment: I agree that is what appears to be happening but thats actually an impossibility seeing as the domain forwarding is setup at the registrar level not the host level. Perhaps this is an issue I should be contacting the registrar about as I am baffled.

Comment: Yes I totally agree. But you can test it. First rename your .htaccess to something else and then visit `domain.com`. Then create a dummy rule e.g. `/foo -> /bar` and visit `domain.com/foo`